# perl + set value in parameter

Tags: perl

With the following example script I try to print the parameter[1] content.
My question is how to print also FLORIDA word (in place $VAL)
so I will get FLORIDA on print output

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @parameter = ();
my $VAL=FLORIDA;

$parameter[1]='45487539
               $VAL
               5847366
               83564566';

print $parameter[1];
```

Output:

```
45487539
               $VAL
               5847366
               83564566
```

Comment: Single quotes do not provide interpolation. Double quotes do. All of this is summarized in a handy table: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators.

Comment: `my $VAL=FLORIDA;` is not valid code above, unless you have declared a `FLORIDA` constant somewhere.

Comment: `my $VAL=FLORIDA` is valid code unless `strict` (specifically `strict subs`) is used. Oh, and you should `use strict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parameter[1]="45487539
               $VAL
               5847366
               83564566";
```

Try that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to replace the single quotes "`'`" with double quotes "`"`".
Now it will work.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to dynamically replace variables from user supplied data, use the following syntax:

```
$parameters[1] =~ s/\$(\w+)\b/eval "return \$$1;"/ge;
print $parameters[1];
```

Comment: Using eval on user-supplied data is a a horrendous security risk.